# How to hidden Application pools but show others in .NET Web setup project?

Tags: .net, iis, web-setup-project

I've create a web setup project. It popup a window to select website, Virtual Directory and application pools. So can anyone tell me how to hidden application pools but show others? Why I want to do this is because I've already create a dedicated application pools, and point this webservice to the dedicated application pools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Orca.exe tool to edit .msi install file, remove or hidden the Application Pool control and label.